# How to Handle unknown display Exception in xCode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

1. I Enabled NSZombie
2. I Enabled Exception Breaking Points

But I unable handle some of exceptions because the Log can't display nothing how to handle this kind of exceptions

[image]

Edited:

```
[CFArray isEqual:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xaa57640
```

Advance Thanks

Comment: what does instrument say?

Comment: Open instruments -> zombies

Comment: Please post a stacktrace.

Comment: which one is can i use from instrument because there are more operations like zombie,allocation,automation.,etc. which one is best to identify there my problem

Comment: i got [CFArray isEqual:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xaa57640 @trojanfoe

Comment: OK, so look in the stacktrace and find which parts of your code is calling that method.  If you want further assistance you'll need to post the full stacktrace and the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You also need set

```
MallocStackLoggingNoCompact = 1
```

in environment variables.

Then for example you have in console

2014-01-18 11:35:24.840 TestApplication[**1621**:10c]  -[NSObject retain]: message sent to deallocated instance **0x12b9140**

It means that NSObject was released. Now you can try to find the place of release using console

```
shell malloc_history 1621 0x12b9140
```

Now in the malloc_history log you can try to find release place.

Comment: Have you tried to get malloc_history at the moment of crash with you [CFArray isEqual:]?